# To find the lcm of two numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was given the task to compute lcm of any two numbers.I have coded in python.The problem is when i compiled  it under python2.7, i got a result which is different from , when i compiled under python3.

```
import sys

def gcd(a,b):     
   if b == 0:
     return a
   remainder = a % b
   return gcd(b,remainder)

def lcm(a, b):
  return int( (a*b) / gcd(a,b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   input = sys.stdin.read()
   a, b = map(int, input.split())
   print(int(lcm(a, b)))
```

**Input**

> 226553150 1023473145

**Output**

> 46374212988031352 (under python3.5)
>
> 46374212988031350 (under python2.7)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2 the division operator `/` will perform integer division, and not float division, when dealing with two integers. You can force the Python 3 behavior in Python 2 by importing division from `__future__`

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 2/3
1.5
```